# Page showing blank but there is content in the code?

Tags: php, html

My page is showing just a white page with no content but the code specifically shows content. Please note that it only happened when there was PHP in the form but that's needed for the system to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Register - Admin Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>

<h3>Register Here : </h3>

<form method='post'>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
if (empty($username) or empty($password));{
echo "<p>Fields Empty</p>";
}else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '2', '')");
echo "<p>Successfully Registered!"</p>";
}
}
?>

User Name: <br/>
<input type='text' name='username' />
<br/><br/>
Password: <br/>
<input type='password' name='password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A blank page means you have an error in your PHP code. What happens when you look at the PHP error log? If you have access to the command line, run your code from there instead of your browser as follows: "php myfile.php"

Answer (score 2):

The two main errors you have are as follows:

1. You closed your if statement with a semi-colon. Remove the semi-colon.
2. You have an extra quote in echo `"<p>Successfully Registered!"</p>"`. Remove the middle quote and it will work.

As I said previously, look at your PHP errors. They will tell you exactly what is wrong.